# How to prevent Pinterest Pin It bookmark link to pick up Google Maps Images

Tags: html, bookmarklet, pinterest

Using Google Maps on my site and when I click on the Pin It bookmarklet imported to the bookmark bar from their pinterest.com/about/goodies/ page, it picks up Google Map images.

How can I specify not to pin images found inside a div tag which contains google map widget?

I cannot individually add nopin attribute to google map images as those tags are generated dynamically by Google Maps library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I have done in my map initialize method.  I am using `jQuery` to add the `nopin` tags to the images after the tiles are loaded.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
    $('#map_canvas').find('img').attr('nopin','nopin');
});
```

Comment: I had to add an event listener for both 'tilesloaded' and 'bounds_changed' map events, but other than that this answer works well

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion other then jQuery?

Answer (score 4):

This is a slightly simpler answer that is a little more robust. I only found your answer after dealing with this myself. Just want to pass along what I learned.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){
    $('div.gm-style img:not([nopin=nopin])').attr('nopin','nopin');
});
```

This will work regardless of your map's id, cuts out the unnecessary `find()`, and only runs against images that are not already marked with nopin. In this way, it won't be negatively affected regardless of how many maps you have on the page.